# Can I access Sharepoint Lists via Web Services from Mono (Unity 3D)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, service, web, unity-container

I am trying to interact with Sharepoint lists via Unity 3D and C#. Most tutorials I have found are for Visual Studio, so it doesn't help me.

I need to be able to read and write to my Sharepoint list.

Anyone have any suggestions? As far as I can tell, this hasn't been done yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Camelot SharePoint Integration Toolkit that extends the Camelot ADO.NET Connector for SharePoint. As long as you can connect to a WCF service you'll be fine.

You can have a look at the PHP Toolkit that matches the Integration Toolkit, here is a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=mDtvcTnTbeM

Resources

- http://camelottoolkit.codeplex.com/
- http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/

Comment: It is unlikely that I'll have access to install plug ins for Sharepoint.

Are the SP Web Services not an option?

Comment: You can install the .NET Connector and the Integration Service on any windows based computer that can reach the SharePoint server, it does not have to be the SharePoint Server itself. The Connector uses the SharePoint API to gain access so by placing this solution in a central server you can use it to gain access to an infinite amount of SharePoint Servers. It's very powerful

Comment: Thank you I will try this method out and see what results I can get!

Comment: Cool, if you run into problem you always get quick help by using the contact form on their web site!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to read and write to SharePoint lists.
You could use the [SharePoint Server 2010 Class Libraries and Web Service References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556847.aspx) or maybe you could use the [SharePoint 2010 Managed Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx).
The most tutorials for accessing the SharePoint Webservices are for Visual Studio, but accessing the SharePoint Webservices has been done with [Javascript](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx) and seemlingy Mono, too (see [MonoTouch, Sharepoint web services and xs:any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823874/monotouch-sharepoint-web-services-and-xsany)).

Comment: The Javascript example is not a direct solution, but I think it may have pointed me in the right direction. Thanks, I'll let you guys know how it works out.